# Saving Images from Client Side using API

Tags: javascript, image, api, express

I have a website that I am rewriting. The Blog area of the website has a featured image - and I am trying to figure out the best way to go about saving the images.

I followed a tutorial that uses the file.mv() function from mongoose (I think from mongoose? Maybe express?) - Either way, it moves the images to a folder inside my public folder.

It works on the dev server but, when I push to Heroku, it does not. I am sure it has something to do with file locations.

I don't know if I am doing this in a traditional way... But Basically I let the blog writer upload the picture and write the post. Then I saved the post content to my bongo db. The file location was saved under the featured image instead of the whole picture being saved under the featured image. That way I didn't have to upload the image to a DB.

Any advice is welcome! Thank!

Here is the code

```
    //save images
blogRouter.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    if(req.files === null ){
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No file uploaded'})
    }

    const file = req.files.file;
    const fileName = file.name.replace(/\s+/g, '');

    file.mv(`${__dirname}/../client/public/BlogImgs/${fileName}`, err => {
        if(err){
            console.error(err)
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }

        res.json({ fileName: fileName, filePath: `/BlogImgs/${fileName}`});
    })
})

//Post New Blog
blogRouter.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let newBlog = new blog({
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content,
        author: req.body.author,
        comments: req.body.comments,
        featuredImg: req.body.featuredImg,
        summary: req.body.summary
    })
    newBlog.save().then(item => res.json(item))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to store it in your DB just store its name and have the image itself in a folder on your server, you can use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) for image uploading.